# compare the strings in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a below-mentioned dataframe:

DF<-

```
ID     source_field_1     field_1      source_field_2    field_2     source_field_3     field_3
ER-1   XY45U              XE34I        Leo Smith         Leo Smith   1992-01-23         23/01/1992
ER-2   AB15X                           Alan joe                      1971-01-23         23/1/1971
ER-3   RT22U              RT22Z        Mark L.A          Mark L A    1962-11-13         3/11/1962
ER-4   ST12R              DT23D        Alan Cox          Ala Cox     1992-01-23         23/01/1992
```

From using the above mentioned data, I have created a dataframe which provides the `Source_field` and `field` are exactly matching or not.

In Addition to that to add the % of match between to columns for each source_field and field and what is the deviation on aggregate of alpha-bate and numbers from 0 to 9

I need to identify the pattern based on count, Like which alpha bate are incorrect entered in the field column when comparing with source column.

For the `Source_field_3` we have date format and `field3` have date in different format we need to identify the date, month and year,

Required Sample Output:

```
Source_field_1     field_1                                     Source_field_1    field_1
A                  A     B      C     D     E  ...... Z        0                 1   2    3 . . . 9
B                                                              1
C                                                              2
D                                                              3
E                                                              4
F                                                              5
G                                                              6
.                                                              .
.                                                              .
.                                                              9
Z
```

Comment: The question is not clear, can you make the expected output more clear? Exactly what should correspond to the posted input?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Expected output would be so long, for the sake of simplicity I have kept it in format basis. I'm just trying to identify the count mismatch basis character and number from `Source` field to `field`.